# Launch "launcher app drawer" from an application?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I would like to launch (or go back) from an application to the `launcher app drawer` with the tiled app icons, not to the desktop.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.launcher","com.android.launcher2.Launcher"));
intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
startActivity(intent);
```

This code "launches" the desktop. I would like to `reach the app icons`. How can I achieve that? The`Manifest of Launcher` doesn't seem to give any activity for this?

Gregoire

Comment: The app drawer is a custom `View`. You can't open it directly from another app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by aneal, you can't call this view as it's not exposed by Android in the launcher app manifest.