# Open Android installed applications screen (app drawer) programmatically

Tags: android

Is there a way (maybe a workaround) to open the Android installed applications screen programmatically?  More than that I want to open the widgets page, but not sure if is possible.
I’ve tried in this way:

```
Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ALL_APPS);
pickIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
pickIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(pickIntent);
```

but `Intent.ACTION_ALL_APPS` actually lists all available applications and using this is closing my app.

Comment: screent shot mean which are upload in android market with app ?

Comment: I want to be able to navigate directly to the installed apps - that screen where you see all the apps installed in your device.

Comment: did you try to check logcat which list is shown when we goto settings -->apps-->download ?

Comment: is not that screen I want - I want the screen with all apps - not apps settings..

Comment: It contain all the apps even preinstalled ,i didnt get exactly which apps list you need to show ?

Comment: this screen: http://www.digitaltrends.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/android-honeycomb-apps-menu.jpg

Comment: He wants to open the app drawer in his application, I think...

Comment: @TobiN: exactly! I didn't knew it is called like that !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Launch "launcher app drawer" from an application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643729/launch-launcher-app-drawer-from-an-application)

Answer (score 1):

You can try like [link](http://impressive-artworx.de/2011/list-all-installed-apps-in-style/) to open the installed application page like a list..

Also can see the answer form [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421527/start-android-application-info-screen)

Comment: Thanks, but what I really want is the screen, not to list myself the applications installed. Going deeper I want actually to create a widget shortcut programatically, but because that is not possible I want to be able at least to go to the screen with installed apps..

Comment: I want to open the app drawer from my application.

Comment: Not sure whether you can directly go to the apps screen page,some days ago i also try that but don't found any solution for that.

Comment: Do you find a solution for ur problem ?