# How to open installed applications drawer android by button click

Tags: java, android

how can I navigate to the applications page on my phone by a button click from my app? is it possible?

**UPDATE**

[image]

Comment: you should do more research before asking.

Comment: @Emmanuel Hello emmanuel thanks for your comment, Yes I have done a bit of research and I am doing research and that's why I am here :)

Comment: are you sure you spend some time to look for the answer and you couldn't find it? It sure doesn't seem like so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Launch "launcher app drawer" from an application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643729/launch-launcher-app-drawer-from-an-application)

Answer (score 1):

The question was not not ver clear earlier. I don't think it's possible. I have worked extensively on Android Launcher code and there's no standard or undocumented Intent to open that page directly.

Comment: this will only let me open a particular package i suppose! I need to open the applications screen that will show me all the applications installed.

Comment: Could you add the screen shot of the particular screen you want to take user to?

Answer (score 1):

Nova Launcher has a shortcut provider which lets you choose any activity. Simply call this shortcut provider from you code and select the activity you want, and then simple record the returned Intent.

Though this intent not be universal for all android versions. It will have package name and component name (and not an action string).

Use this code in an Activity in a test project. Make sure you have Nova launcher installed (you can uninstall it later on)

```
public void onTestButtonClicked(View v) {
  startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT), "Select Activities"), 10);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (requestCode == 10 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    Intent intent = data.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT);
    Log.e("Intent", intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME));
  }
}
```

Comment: hey thanks :) is it possible for you to provide me with an example please?

Comment: Thanks Painless! but can I not use with the android default launcher?

Comment: You can use it with the default launcher, you just need the Nova launcher to be installed, since it comes the the "Activities" picker. Also this would be a one time thing to find out the intent and this code should not be in the final app