# How to Launch Apps Screen Programmatically in Android

Tags: android

I want to programmatically launch the apps screen. Anyone know how?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sz7hJ.png]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Launch "launcher app drawer" from an application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643729/launch-launcher-app-drawer-from-an-application)

Answer (score 0):

You want to launch the **launcher**
If you have the default android Home you can use:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER));
```

Comment: This doesn't open the "All Apps" screen